# Algorithm to get items from nested array structure structured around powers of 2

Tags: arrays, algorithm, tree

I have some constraints on how an array would be implemented under the hood. There can only be power-of-two contiguous elements up to 32 elements (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32). Therefore, this puts some constraints on how to optimally store the array elements of like 7 or 15 elements, etc.. The full list of examples from 1 to 32 is [here](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/11d1bcb4dbd8985edcaf44eee2db89f8), but some examples are next:

```
base-3
  a
  b
  c
  null

base-5
  a
  b
  c
  tree
    d
    e

base-6
  a
  b
  c
  d
  e
  f
  null
  null

...

base-10
  a
  b
  c
  d
  e
  f
  g
  tree
    h
    i
    j
    null

...

base-13
  tree
    a
    b
    c
    d
  tree
    e
    f
    g
    h
  tree
    i
    j
    k
    l
  tree
    m

...

base-16
  a
  b
  c
  d
  e
  f
  g
  h
  i
  j
  k
  l
  m
  n
  o
  p

base-17
  a
  b
  c
  d
  e
  f
  g
  h
  i
  j
  k
  l
  m
  n
  o
  tree
    p
    q
```

Null is chosen in a few cases because it would take up less space to just have a null value than to make it into an appropriate tree (or using null would mean less traversal steps).

At 32, it should nest the pattern, like this:

```
base-33
  tree
    a
    b
    c
    d
    e
    f
    g
    h
    i
    j
    k
    l
    m
    n
    o
    p
    q
    r
    s
    t
    u
    v
    w
    x
    y
    z
    aa
    ab
    ac
    ad
    ae
    af
  tree
    ag
```

The `tree` key just shows it is an address linking out to another array.

I started to implement an algorithm to fetch all the values from this tree system below. I didn't find a way of generically making it so I didn't have to write each of 32 functions. If you know of an abstract/generic way to write this, that would be cool to know (doesn't need to exactly match how I divided up the arrays, but it should be close to the same idea). But that is not the main question. The main question is simply **how you would make this function repeat for arrays larger than 32.** How do you make this algorithm (a loop/iterative algorithm, not using recursion) so that it can fetch up to billions of items from such a tree, and know how to traverse the custom array structure?

```
const map = [
  get1,
  get2,
  get3,
  get4,
  get5,
  get6,
  get7,
  get8,
  get9,
  get10,
  get11,
  get12,
  get13,
  get14,
  get15,
  get16,
  get17,
  get18,
  get19,
  get20,
  get21,
  get22,
  get23,
  get24,
  get25,
  get26,
  get27,
  get28,
  get29,
  get30,
  get31,
  get32,
]

// how to make getItems handle arrays larger than 32 in length?
function getItems(array) {
  return map[array.length](array)
}

function get1(array) {
  return [
    array[0]
  ]
}

function get2(array) {
  return [
    array[0],
    array[1],
  ]
}

function get3(array) {
  return [
    array[0],
    array[1],
    array[2],
  ]
}

function get4(array) {
  return [
    array[0],
    array[1],
    array[2],
    array[3],
  ]
}

function get5(array) {
  return [
    array[0],
    array[1],
    array[2],
    array[3][0],
    array[3][1],
  ]
}

function get6(array) {
  return [
    array[0],
    array[1],
    array[2],
    array[3],
    array[4],
    array[5],
  ]
}

function get7(array) {
  return [
    array[0],
    array[1],
    array[2],
    array[3],
    array[4],
    array[5],
    array[6],
  ]
}

function get8(array) {
  return [
    array[0],
    array[1],
    array[2],
    array[3],
    array[4],
    array[5],
    array[6],
    array[7],
  ]
}

function get9(array) {
  return [
    array[0],
    array[1],
    array[2],
    array[3],
    array[4],
    array[5],
    array[6],
    array[7][0],
    array[7][1],
  ]
}

function get10(array) {
  return [
    array[0],
    array[1],
    array[2],
    array[3],
    array[4],
    array[5],
    array[6],
    array[7][0],
    array[7][1],
    array[7][2],
  ]
}

function get11(array) {
  return [
    array[0],
    array[1],
    array[2],
    array[3],
    array[4],
    array[5],
    array[6],
    array[7][0],
    array[7][1],
    array[7][2],
    array[7][3],
  ]
}

function get12(array) {
  return [
    array[0][0],
    array[1][1],
    array[2][2],
    array[3][3],
    array[4][4],
    array[5][5],
    array[6][6],
    array[6][7],
    array[7][0],
    array[7][1],
    array[7][2],
    array[7][3],
  ]
}
```

I am lost right at the beginning. It could be implemented with recursion, and perhaps from that I can figure it out as an imperative form.

```
function getItemsRecursive(tree) {
  if (tree.size <= 32) {
    return map[tree.size](tree)
  }

  // ... I am lost right at the beginning.

  if (tree.size === 33) {
    return [
      ...getItemsRecursive(tree[0]),
      tree[1][0]
    ]
  } else if (tree.size === 34) {
    // ....?
  }
}
```

The `tree.size` is just pseudocode. You can just do pseudocode if you'd like, but I am doing this in JavaScript.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but if you're just looking to traverse a structure of nested arrays, what's wrong with depth-first search? Is the tree height so large that you'd run out of memory?

Comment: I don't understand what the expected return value is: you want to return from a given array, ... an array? Isn't that the same thing? The last snippet seems to just replicate the original tree. Or are you looking for a function that also gets a sequence number as input (an "index"), such that the returned value is the corresponding value from the tree?

Comment: @trincot I guess what I am asking is to return a _flattened array_ from the nested array. A similar question (which could be answered instead) is how you would iterate over more than 32 elements in this tree structure. I could iterate over up-to 32 elements using my hardcoded method, but how could that be extended to work on an arbitrary number of elements in the tree.

Comment: NB: on your github link I see examples where the root level has a non-power-of-2 number of elements, like for 20: there are 8 atomic values (`a-g, t`) and 2 subtrees, so 10 root-children in total.

Comment: Oh whoops, I will have to fix that. Thank you for pointing out the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript you would of course call `.flat(Infinity)`, which would return the completely flattened array. But I'll assume these constraints:

- No use of array methods besides `push` and `pop` (as you target a custom, simpler language)
- No use of recursion
- No use of a generator or iterator

I hope the use of a stack is acceptable. I would then think of a stack where each stacked element consists of an array reference and an index in that array. But to avoid "complex" stack elements, we can also use two stacks: one for array references, another for the indices in those arrays.

To implement "iteration", I will use a callback system, so that you can specify what should happen in each iteration. The callback can be `console.log`, so that the iterated value is just output.

Here is an implementation:

```js
function iterate(arr, callback) {
    let arrayStack = [];
    let indexStack = [];
    let i = 0;
    while (true) {
        if (i >= arr.length || arr[i] === null) {
            if (arrayStack.length == 0) return; // all done
            arr = arrayStack.pop();
            i = indexStack.pop();
        } else if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
            arrayStack.push(arr);
            indexStack.push(i + 1);
            arr = arr[i];
            i = 0;
        } else {
            callback(arr[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]];

iterate(arr, console.log);
```

Comment: Oh this is interesting, why didn't I think of that lol. This is very different than where I was headed, so that's great that this solves it! I guess I was fixated on the actual specific structure of each of the 32 instances. Is there a way that this could be optimized so it uses the specific structural info of each (or close to them, as it looks like I made some errors in defining them). Like how I started hardcoding each function, somehow calling that recursively (but iteratively). I will let this sink in though, maybe this is what I needed instead :) Thank you!!!

Comment: In my case specifically, this is for a custom programming language. I was imagining having nodes in a graph have links defined like a Rails model (attribute names, but laid out in memory by index in an array). So if there are 64 attributes, it would lay them out in a tree like described. Then the goal is to fetch the attributes. So this won't necessarily be a JavaScript specific solution, so the generalness of this solutions is great, but still curious if it would benefit from the hardcoding at all. Thinking being that it limits the jumps or something, I'm not totally sure.

Comment: I don't see a way to benefit from hardcoding, as it looks like in general *any* entry could be a subtree or an atomic value. Although I can see that once an entry is a subtree, it would be expected that any siblings *after* that subtree would also be subtree (I am a bit curious why in the example for 20, `t` is dangling at the end and violating this expectation). You could maybe also make assumptions about the maximum depth of a tree, as this would be O(logn) and so we can be quite sure the depth will never exceed 50, and so you can preallocate that memory for the stacks.

Comment: I think you should resist the temptation to hardcode for the known shapes, since that means whenever you change your mind on how to best shape an array (for a certain size), you also need to refactor the code.

Comment: That makes sense. I [refactored the output](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/11d1bcb4dbd8985edcaf44eee2db89f8) to have more of a "pattern", but I still can't pinpoint the pattern exactly yet. Ideally there would be a pattern to it :)

Comment: For 20, you may prefer `abcdefghijklmn[op][qrst]`

Comment: Ooh nice syntax too.