# How to support 256 values without null in array-tree pattern generator?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I love [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71091623/how-to-make-tree-pattern-fit-constraints-but-so-algorithm-is-generic-instead-of/71096085#71096085) to that question, it's so creative and robust. I translated it to support 256 values without supporting null arrays, and the tree/array `shape` generation seems to work. However, I am stuck on how the encoding radix-like function works, and how to translate that given that now `POSSIBLE_SHAPE_LIST` is only 9 elements instead of 16 now. How do I get `getPath` to appropriate put the path to the value in the tree structure, given the index? Here is the full code:

```js
const POSSIBLE_SHAPE_LIST = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256]
const CODE_LIST = collect()

console.log(CODE_LIST.join('\n'))
console.log(getPath(28, 21))

function getPath(size, i) {
  let code = CODE_LIST[size - 1]
  let limit = POSSIBLE_SHAPE_LIST[code % POSSIBLE_SHAPE_LIST.length]

  if (i < limit) {
    return [i]
  }

  for (let sub = 1; sub < 6; sub++) {
    i -= limit
    code /= 9
    limit = POSSIBLE_SHAPE_LIST[code % POSSIBLE_SHAPE_LIST.length]
    if (i < limit) {
      return [sub, i]
    }
  }
}

function collect() {
  let codes = []

  for (let n = 1; n <= 256; n++) {
    let shapeNumbers = shape(n)
    let code = encode(shapeNumbers)
    codes.push(code)
  }

  return codes
}

function encode(shapeNumbers) {
  let code = 0

  for (let i = shapeNumbers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    code = code * POSSIBLE_SHAPE_LIST.length + POSSIBLE_SHAPE_LIST.indexOf(shapeNumbers[i])
  }

  return code
}

/**
 * Returns number of atomic entries,
 * followed by data-size(s) of subarrays
 */

function shape(n) {
  let p = greatestPowerOf2(n);
  if (p >= n) {
    // The only cases where there are no subarrays
    return [n];
  }

  // Try with one subarray
  for (let sub = 2; sub < n && sub <= 256; sub *= 2) {
    let top = n - sub + 1;
    p = greatestPowerOf2(top);
    if (p >= top) {
      return [p - 1, sub];
    }
  }

  // Try with two subarrays
  for (let sub1 = 2; sub1 < n && sub1 <= 256; sub1 *= 2) {
    for (let sub2 = 2; sub2 <= sub1; sub2 *= 2) {
      let top = n - sub1 - sub2 + 2;
      if (top < 0) break;
      p = greatestPowerOf2(top);
      if (p >= top) {
        return [p - 2, sub1, sub2];
      }
    }
  }

  // Try with three subarrays
  for (let sub1 = 2; sub1 < n && sub1 <= 256; sub1 *= 2) {
    for (let sub2 = 2; sub2 <= sub1; sub2 *= 2) {
      for (let sub3 = 2; sub3 <= sub2; sub3 *= 2) {
        let top = n - sub1 - sub2 - sub3 + 3;
        if (top < 0) break;
        p = greatestPowerOf2(top);
        if (p >= top) {
          return [p - 3, sub1, sub2, sub3];
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Try with four subarrays
  for (let sub1 = 2; sub1 < n && sub1 <= 256; sub1 *= 2) {
    for (let sub2 = 2; sub2 <= sub1; sub2 *= 2) {
      for (let sub3 = 2; sub3 <= sub2; sub3 *= 2) {
        for (let sub4 = 2; sub4 <= sub3; sub4 *= 2) {
          let top = n - sub1 - sub2 - sub3 - sub4 + 4;
          if (top < 0) break;
          p = greatestPowerOf2(top);
          if (p >= top) {
            return [p - 4, sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Try with five subarrays
  for (let sub1 = 2; sub1 < n && sub1 <= 256; sub1 *= 2) {
    for (let sub2 = 2; sub2 <= sub1; sub2 *= 2) {
      for (let sub3 = 2; sub3 <= sub2; sub3 *= 2) {
        for (let sub4 = 2; sub4 <= sub3; sub4 *= 2) {
          for (let sub5 = 2; sub5 <= sub4; sub5 *= 2) {
            let top = n - sub1 - sub2 - sub3 - sub4 - sub5 + 5;
            if (top < 0) break;
            p = greatestPowerOf2(top);
            if (p >= top) {
              return [p - 5, sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4, sub5];
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Try with 6 subarrays
  for (let sub1 = 2; sub1 < n && sub1 <= 256; sub1 *= 2) {
    for (let sub2 = 2; sub2 <= sub1; sub2 *= 2) {
      for (let sub3 = 2; sub3 <= sub2; sub3 *= 2) {
        for (let sub4 = 2; sub4 <= sub3; sub4 *= 2) {
          for (let sub5 = 2; sub5 <= sub4; sub5 *= 2) {
            for (let sub6 = 2; sub6 <= sub5; sub6 *= 2) {
              let top = n - sub1 - sub2 - sub3 - sub4 - sub5 - sub6 + 6;
              if (top < 0) break;
              p = greatestPowerOf2(top);
              if (p >= top) {
                return [p - 6, sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4, sub5, sub6];
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Try with 7 subarrays
  for (let sub1 = 2; sub1 < n && sub1 <= 256; sub1 *= 2) {
    for (let sub2 = 2; sub2 <= sub1; sub2 *= 2) {
      for (let sub3 = 2; sub3 <= sub2; sub3 *= 2) {
        for (let sub4 = 2; sub4 <= sub3; sub4 *= 2) {
          for (let sub5 = 2; sub5 <= sub4; sub5 *= 2) {
            for (let sub6 = 2; sub6 <= sub5; sub6 *= 2) {
              for (let sub7 = 2; sub7 <= sub6; sub7 *= 2) {
                let top = n - sub1 - sub2 - sub3 - sub4 - sub5 - sub6 - sub7 + 7;
                if (top < 0) break;
                p = greatestPowerOf2(top);
                if (p >= top) {
                  return [p - 7, sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4, sub5, sub6, sub7];
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  throw new Error(n)
}

function greatestPowerOf2(n) {
  return n >= 256 ? 256 : n >= 128 ? 128 : n >= 64 ? 64 : n >= 32 ? 32 : n >= 16 ? 16 : n >= 8 ? 8 : n >= 4 ? 4 : n >= 2 ? 2 : 1;
}
```

It should not log (at the end) `[21]`, it should log something like `[14, 1]` following the pattern laid out [here](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/2c9f31c560d41dbe3119983b1eeeb728). What am I doing wrong in the translation from the original answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues to fix:

1. `POSSIBLE_SHAPE_LIST = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256]` is only listing the possible values that represent subarrays, but it does not list all possible values for the first element in a shape representation, i.e. the number of atomic values that are not in a nested array. This number does not have to be a power of 2. For instance, the shape for size 28 is [12, 4, 4, 4], which means that there are 3 subarrays of size 4, but also 12 top-level slots. That 12 is not a power of 2, but still needs to be encoded.
2. `code /= 9` will perform a floating point division (unlike in Java). And also, that 9 should not be hardcoded since you have a constant for it.

   So write: `code = Math.floor(code /  POSSIBLE_SHAPE_LIST.length)`

For resolving the first issue, I would propose to split the `collect` functionality into steps:

1. Collect all the shapes without encoding them
2. Collect the distinct numbers that are used in those shapes and assign that to `POSSIBLE_SHAPE_LIST`
3. Perform the encoding of those shapes.

So the script could start with this:

```
let shapes = collectShapes(); // Step 1
const POSSIBLE_SHAPE_LIST = getUsedNumbers(shapes); // Step 2
console.log(POSSIBLE_SHAPE_LIST);  // Demonstrate that list has 35 instead of 9 values
const CODE_LIST = shapes.map(encode); // Step 3

console.log(CODE_LIST.join('\n'));
console.log("the shape for size 28 is ", shapes[27]); // for debugging
console.log(getPath(28, 21)); // [3, 1]

function getUsedNumbers(shapes) {
  const usedNumberSet = new Set([1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256]);
  for (const shapeNumbers of shapes) {
    usedNumberSet.add(shapeNumbers[0]);
  }
  // Not really necessary to sort, but it is a nice-to-have
  return [...usedNumberSet].sort((a, b) => a - b); 
}

function collectShapes() {
  let shapes = [];
  for (let n = 1; n <= 256; n++) {
    shapes.push(shape(n));
  }
  return shapes;
}
```

NB: I have the habit to terminate statements with semi-colons, as I don't want to be dependent on the [automatic semi-colon insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi) algorithm.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of semicolons, it's my habit with many of the teams I've joined lol. But now this team I'm on is using them again, back and forth and back and forth :)

Comment: Now to [optimize](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/274137/how-to-optimize-push-and-pop-in-this-tree-list-algorithm) `push` and `pop`, I am going to be working on this in the coming days more than I've already tried. Not quite as hard as the original problem though, but still tricky! I gotta get to the point where you are with coming up with such good algorithms.